# Can XSLT be used to merge child elements in a document based on nested keys

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I was wondering if it is possible using XSL to merge elements in a document. Specifically for the below example.

I want to merge  elements so that the  ones are effectively aggregated including any additional descendents (grandchildren) as well.

Note that the key for the Child implicitly includes the parent so 123/ABC is different to 456/ABC.

A nice to know would also be around how to determine the the nodes that "Wins" for ones where an overwrite occurs (such as parent/name).

From this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listOfParent>
<parent>
    <parentId>123</parentId>
    <name>Jim</name>
    <value>some data</value>
    <listOfChild>
        <child>
            <childReference>ABC</childReference>
            <name>Karen</name>
        </child>
    </listOfChild>
</parent>
<parent>
    <parentId>123</parentId>
    <name>Fred</name>
    <listOfChild>
        <child>
            <childReference>ABC</childReference>
            <name>Gemma</name>
        </child>
        <child>
            <childReference>DEF</childReference>
            <name>Karen</name>
        </child>
    </listOfChild>
</parent>
<parent>
    <parentId>456</parentId>
    <name>Bill</name>
    <listOfChild>
        <child>
            <childReference>ABC</childReference>
            <name>Penny</name>
        </child>
        <child>
            <childReference>DEF</childReference>
            <name>Rose</name>
        </child>
    </listOfChild>
</parent>
```

to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listOfParent>
<parent>
    <parentId>123</parentId>
    <name>not bothered</name>
    <value>some data</value>
    <listOfChild>
        <child>
            <childReference>ABC</childReference>
            <name>not bothered</name>
        </child>
        <child>
            <childReference>DEF</childReference>
            <name>Karen</name>
        </child>
    </listOfChild>
</parent>
<parent>
    <parentId>456</parentId>
    <name>Bill</name>
    <listOfChild>
        <child>
            <childReference>ABC</childReference>
            <name>Penny</name>
        </child>
        <child>
            <childReference>DEF</childReference>
            <name>Rose</name>
        </child>
    </listOfChild>
</parent>
```

Here is the XSL I tried

```
<?altova_samplexml Untitled1.xml?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:key name="kGDByIdKey" match="parent" use="parentId"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="parent
[generate-id()
=
 generate-id(key('kGDByIdKey', parentId)[1])
 ]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|key('kGDByIdKey', parentId)/node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="parent"/>
```

Comment: Yes, it can. (Though I presume your intended question was "how can...")

Comment: :-) Yes that would be helpful

Comment: I tried using existing examples found on this site that looked similar, with no success

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and we'll point out what you got wrong. (I presume you *did* rewrite those examples to work with your document structure, right?)

Comment: Also, you need to explain what the logic is for "not bothered".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900006/group-merge-childs-of-same-nodes-in-xml-xslt

Was my starting point

By "not bothered" I mean I'll figure out that bit out myself hopefully. In terms of which source value is used in the result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900006/group-merge-childs-of-same-nodes-in-xml-xslt

Was my starting point, I simply replaced GroupData with parent as follows (still figuring out how to get code into comment)




By "not bothered" I mean I'll figure out that bit out myself hopefully. In terms of which source value is used in the result.